# WCF bindings from XML

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

This is a bit odd, but I was wondering if anyone knows if there is a way to get Binding objects from XML code defined in an app.config file.  For example, lets say that this was the XML that I wished to parse.

```
<basicHttpBinding>
  <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_MyService" ...settings.../>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

Is there a class or something that I can feed this into to get a 'BasicHttpBinding' object that contains all of the settings? i.e.
`BasicHttpBinding b = Something.ParseBindingXML(xmlData)`;

Obviously the data in the app.config file is getting parsed and converted at some point, but is this mechanism available, and if so, how can I use it?

And yes, I know that this isn't standard practice, and isn't the right way to do things, etc. so please refrain from mentioning that in your response.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a built-in class you can use from within code that would do that for you, but if you're hosting in IIS and using a Web.config you can use the configSource attribute to put your bindings in a separate xml file like so:

```
<bindings configSource="bindings.xml" />
```

Then you would put your bindings in the bindings.xml file, whose contents would look something like this:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_MyService" ...settings.../>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

If you wanted to read in the xml and create your bindings on the fly within code, you might have to code that yourself, although somebody may come along and prove me wrong.

Comment: Yes, I fear that I may have to do it myself, but it just feels like I'd be repeating work that is already available.